# How to create a short modal overlay like the iOS Share Sheet menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I’m trying to create a custom, short menu that slides up from the bottom of the screen and stays at the bottom (like the iOS share sheet). I’m having a hard time trying to figure out how to do it. I tried presenting a view controller as a modal and setting the preferred content size, but it still presents it as full screen. How can I present a short, modal-like overlay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a UIPresentationController and a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate.

As a starting point here a few lines of code:

**UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate**

```
class OverlayTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController:presented, presenting:presenting)
    }

}
```

**UIPresentationController**

```
class OverlayPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    private let dimmedBackgroundView = UIView()
    private let height: CGFloat = 200.0

    override init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?) {
        super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundTapped))
        self.dimmedBackgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        var frame =  CGRect.zero
        if let containerBounds = containerView?.bounds {
            frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                           y: containerBounds.height - height,
                           width: containerBounds.width,
                           height: height)
        }
        return frame
    }

    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        if let containerView = self.containerView, let coordinator = presentingViewController.transitionCoordinator {
            containerView.addSubview(self.dimmedBackgroundView)
            self.dimmedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
            self.dimmedBackgroundView.frame = containerView.bounds
            self.dimmedBackgroundView.alpha = 0
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
                self.dimmedBackgroundView.alpha = 0.5
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func dismissalTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
        self.dimmedBackgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @objc private func backgroundTapped() {
       self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

**How to call it**

```
let overlayTransitioningDelegate = OverlayTransitioningDelegate()

@IBAction func onOpenModalOverlay(_ sender: Any) {
    let overlayVC = OverlayViewController()
    overlayVC.transitioningDelegate  = self.overlayTransitioningDelegate
    overlayVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    self.present(overlayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Demo**

The OverlayViewController is a normal ViewController. Here I used an ugly green background color to make it easier to recognize the overlay.

[image: overlay demo]